# Reading binary data from a file with a given structure

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, binary

I'm stuck here with the problem of reading a binary data from a file (*.ADB) which is an output of a seismic station. 
The primary idea here is to read the data from *.ADB and to save it as unpacked structured ASCII file that's going to be read by a next script in DSP chain or looked through with any table processor or CAD software.

I've requested a file structure from it's creators and it goes as follows:

1. firstly there's a header consisting of different tech and meta info:

   ```
   PARAMETER NAME       | OFFSET (WORDS) | PARAMETER SIZE

   station name                0                 36

   station #                   18                 2

   profile #                   19                 2

   observation point #         20                 2

   shotpoint #                 21                 2

   ...etc

   sample format               35                 2

   ...etc
   ```
2. then it's said that if sample format is '0' then data structure looks as follows:

   ```
   15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

   15 – sign, 0=1 (positive number), 1=-1 (negative number)
   14-13 – channel number
   12-10 – order
   9-0 – fixed point part
   ```
3. samples are stored in a special structure:

   ```
   CHANNEL NUMBER | PARAMETER | PARAMETER SIZE (WORDS)
          1        maxAmp/Chn1        4
                   first sample       2
                   ...etc
                   last sample        2
          N        ...etc
   ```

I know that the number of active seismic station channels is 3 (for Z, X and Y components of a seismic signal), but I have no idea about the actual sample format since I haven't read the header yet.

So the first thing to do is reading that header, what should I use, 'struct' or 'bitstring'? I'm running 'little-endian' windows machine.

Ok, let me reveal a bit of the actual code (works for me to read the header):

```
# importing all the needed modules
import struct
# open binary file in a read mode
file = open('C:/01.adb', 'rb')
# creating array of header data block sizes
readsize = (36,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,2,2,2,2,2,10,2,4,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,126)
print('Readsize array length: '+str(len(readsize)))
# guessing the header structure with python data types, creating structure
formatstring = '<36s H H H H H H H H H H H H H H H I H H H H H 10s H f f f 4s f H H H H H H H H H 126s'
adbstruct = struct.Struct(formatstring)
# calculating guessed little-endian fmt (formatstring) size
print('Calculated structure size: '+str(struct.calcsize(formatstring)))
# calculating header block size based on 'readsize' array (usually 256 bytes for *.ADB)
packed_size = 0
for i in range(len(readsize)): packed_size = packed_size+readsize[i]
print('Calculated header size: '+str(packed_size)+'\n')
# reading packed data of 'packed_size' length
packed_data = file.read(packed_size)
file.close()
# printing header represented in data types defined by formatstring
print(struct.unpack(formatstring,packed_data))
```

The code above does it's job (I guess, since a couple of parameters I get have expected values), here's that script output:

```
Readsize array length: 39
Calculated structure size: 256
Calculated header size: 256

(b'LogiS (C)2000, DELTA Software, V2.6 ', 143, 1, 1, 1, 12, 5, 29, 8, 0, 2, 800, 35, 1, 1, 3, 513024, 2, 1, 1, 33604, 65519, b'\x12U\x0e\x00\x86\x0b\x12\x00\xd7\xed', 1, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, b'\x00\x00\x00\x00', 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
```

What I'm doing next is reading the data block, I guess I'm dividing overall sample number by the number of channels 513024/3=171008. That means that I'm gonna have to read 171008 blocks of size 2 and 1 preceding block of size 4 for each channel.

sample format byte says it's '2' which is not really what I expected, it's okay though. After reading the 2-byte sample, how do I perform it's bit-by-bit processing?

It's said that sample format '2' represents 32-bit words with complementary code for storing negative numbers, I guess there might be some nice way to read packs of theese in python?

Comment: You're going to want the `struct` module.

Comment: Actually it's unclear if you want SO to write code for you. It'd be better if you show what you have so people can comment on it. As for ideas, I suggest using regular expressions (`re` module) to parse text data with a simple structure, and to use the `struct` module to analyse binary data.

Comment: tnx, I added some code and asked the question on bit-by-bit access :)